# BPS profile decryption issue after migrating from IS 5.10 to 6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After migrating WSO2 IS 5.10 to 6.0 I was able to notice the following error at the server startup.

```
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:15,088] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.internal.WorkflowImplServiceComponent} - Error occured while adding default bps profile. org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplException: Error while decrypting the password for BPEL Profile embeded_bps
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.getBPSProfile(BPSProfileDAO.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplServiceImpl.getBPSProfile(WorkflowImplServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.internal.WorkflowImplServiceComponent.addDefaultBPSProfile(WorkflowImplServiceComponent.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.internal.WorkflowImplServiceComponent.activate(WorkflowImplServiceComponent.java:91)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    ...
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoException: An error occurred while decrypting data.
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:317)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.base64DecodeAndDecrypt(CryptoUtil.java:431)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.decryptPassword(BPSProfileDAO.java:314)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.getBPSProfile(BPSProfileDAO.java:156)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.crypto.api.CryptoException: An error occurred while decrypting using the algorithm : 'AES/GCM/NoPadding'
    at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider.decrypt(SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider.java:152)
    at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.DefaultCryptoService.decrypt(DefaultCryptoService.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:311)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider.decrypt(SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider.java:135)
    ... 130 more
```

The issue seems to be due to `embedded_bps` profile. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur due to one of the following reasons.

1. The `encryption` configuration in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file is not configured properly. If you have created an encryption key before the migration using `openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -k <YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT_KEY> -P` and you have somehow commented that after the migration.

In this case you have to add the `encryption` key that you have used during the data migration.

```
[encryption]
key="xxxxxx"
```

2. If you have defined an incorrect crypto provider in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file(`encryption.internal_crypto_provider`), you will be seeing this error as well. In that case, comment out that configuration and use the default `internal_crypto_provider` configuration.
3. If you have pointed the `identity_db` with another WSO2 product(e.g. APIM) and it uses another encryption algorithm, then this error can occur as well. In this case, you can check the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.properties`, `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` files to figure out the `encryption` configurations you have set up in WSO2 IS. In this case, you have to either use the same algorithm with both products.

- For example, if the `embedded_bps` profile password in the IS had persisted with symmetric key encryption initially but now since the encryption has been changed to asymmetric to match with APIM you have to delete the default `embedded_bps` profile and restart the server again. During the restart `embedded_bsp_profile` will be created again. To delete the `embedded _bps` profile run the following command in the `identity_db`.

```
DELETE FROM WF_BPS_PROFILE WHERE PROFILE_NAME='embeded_bps';
```